# How to call Connect middleware directly?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a express route like this:

```
app.get('/', auth.authOrDie, function(req, res) {
    res.send();
});
```

where `authOrDie` function is defined like that (in my `auth.js` module):

```
exports.authOrDie = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    } else {
        res.send(403);
    }
});
```

Now, when the user is not authenticated, I would like to verify if the http request has a Authorization (Basic) header. To do that, I would like to use the great connect middleware [basicAuth()](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-basicAuth.html).

As you know, Express is built on top of Connect, so I can use `express.basicAuth`.

The `basicAuth` is generally used like that:

```
app.get('/', express.basicAuth(function(username, password) {
    // username && password verification...
}), function(req, res) {
    res.send();
});
```

But, I would like to use it in my `authOrDie` function like that:

```
exports.authOrDie = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    } else if {
        // express.basicAuth ??? ******
    } else {
        res.send(403);
    }
});
```

How can I call the basicAuth function with the good parameters (req ? res ? next ? ...).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling the `express.basicAuth` function returns the middleware function to call, so you'd invoke it directly like this:

```
exports.authOrDie = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    } else {
        return express.basicAuth(function(username, password) {
            // username && password verification...
        })(req, res, next);
    }
});
```